# how can i separate text area and edit separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable

i would like to separate text area the problem is that when i write something on one of them they all have the same text and i would like to submit each one separately. i have been having lots of trouble trying to make this work please help me i would also like to edit the text individually if i need to change my code i would really appreciate it as long as it works

```js
var z = 1; //value to make div overlappable

$('#addText').click(function (e) {
    /** Make div draggable **/
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'ui-widget-content',
        appendTo: '.container',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent',
            start: function( event, ui ) {
                $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
            }
        }
    });
});


$(document).on("dblclick", '.text', function()
{
    $(this).hide();    $(this).closest('.item').find('.edit_text').val($(this).text()).show();
});

$(document).on("click", ".edit_text", function()
{
    return false;
});


$(document).on("click", function()
{
    var editingText = $('.edit_text:visible');
    if (editingText.length)
    {
        editingText.hide();
        editingText.closest('.item').find('.text').text($(editingText).val()).show();
    }
});

ko.bindingHandlers.draggable={
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $(element).draggable();
    }
};

var vm=function(){
    var self=this;
    self.items=ko.observableArray();
    self.textContent = ko.observable('');
    self.init=function(){
        self.items([]);
    }
    self.remove=function(item){
        console.log(item);
        self.items.remove(item);
    }
    self.addNew = function() {
      self.items.push( self.textContent() );
      self.textContent('');
    }
    self.init();
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());


$('.thumbs img').click(function() {
    var thmb = this;
    var src  = this.src;
    $(thmb).parent('.thumbs').prev('.bottlesWrapper').find('img').fadeOut(400,function(){
        thmb.src = this.src;
        $(this).fadeIn(400)[0].src = src;
    });
});








$("#fs").change(function() {
    //alert($(this).val());
    $('.item3').css("font-family", $(this).val());

});

$("#size").change(function() {
    $('.item2').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});


$('.foo').click(function(){
 $('.item1').css("color", $(this).attr('data-color'));
});
```

```html
  <select id="fs"> 
        <option value="Agency FB">Agency FB</option>
        <option value="Algerian">Algerian</option>
        <option value="AR Berkley">AR Berkley</option>
        <option value="AR Blanca">AR Blanca</option>
        <option value="AR Bonnie">AR Bonnie</option>
        <option value="AR Carter">AR Carter</option>
        <option value="AR Cena">AR Cena</option>
        <option value="AR Christy">AR Christy</option>
        <option value="AR Darling">AR Darling</option>
        <option value="AR Decode">AR Decode</option>
        <option value="AR Delaney">AR Delaney</option>
        <option value="AR Destine">AR Destine</option>
        <option value="AR Essence">AR Essence</option>
        <option value="AR HERMANN">AR Hermann</option>
        <option value="AR JULIAN">AR Julian</option>
        <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
        <option value="Arial Black">Arial Black</option>
        <option value="Arial Narrow">Arial Narrow</option>
        <option value="Arial Rounded MT Bold">Arial Rounded MT Bold</option>
        <option value="Baskerville Old Face">Baskerville Old Face</option>
        <option value="Bell MT">Bell MT</option>
        <option value="Berlin Sans FB">Berlin Sans FB</option>
        <option value="Berlin Sans FB Demi">Berlin Sans FB Demi</option>
        <option value="Bernard MT Condensed">Bernard MT Condensed</option>
        <option value="Blackadder ITC">Blackadder ITC</option>
        <option value="Bodoni MT">Bodoni MT</option>
        <option value="Bodoni MT Black">Bodoni MT Black</option>
        <option value="Bodoni MT Condensed">Bodoni MT Condensed</option>
        <option value="Bodoni MT Poster Compressed">Bodoni MT Poster Compressed</option>
        <option value="Book Antiqua">Book Antiqua</option>
        <option value="Bookman Old Style">Bookman Old Style</option>
        <option value="Bradley Hand ITC">Bradley Hand ITC</option>   
        <option value="Britannic Bold">Britannic Bold</option>
        <option value="Broadway">Broadway</option>
        <option value="Brush Script MT">Brush Script MT</option>
        <option value="Bodoni MT">Bodoni MT</option>
        <option value="Californian FB">Californian FB</option>
        <option value="Castellar">Castellar</option>
        <option value="Century Gothic">Century Gothic</option>
        <option value="Century Schoolbook">Century Schoolbook</option> 
        <option value="Chiller">Chiller</option>
        <option value="Colonna MT">Colonna MT</option> 
        <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
        <option value="Constantia">Constantia</option>
        <option value="Cooper Black">Cooper Black</option>
        <option value="Copperplate Gothic Bold">Copperplate Gothic Bold</option>
        <option value="Copperplate Gothic Light">Copperplate Gothic Light</option>
        <option value="Curlz MT">Curlz MT</option>
        <option value="Edwardian Script ITC">Edwardian Script ITC</option> 
       <option value="Elephant">Elephant</option>
       <option value="Engravers MT">Engravers MT</option>
       <option value="Eras Bold ITC">Eras Bold ITC</option>
       <option value="Eras Demi ITC">Eras Demi ITC</option>
       <option value="Eras Light ITC">Eras Light ITC</option>
       <option value="Eras Medium ITC">Eras Medium ITC</option>
       <option value="Felix Titling">Felix Titling</option>
       <option value="Footling MT Light">Footling MT Light</option>
       <option value="Forte">Forte</option>
    </select>
<select id="size">
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="32">32</option>
        <option value="34">34</option>
        <option value="36">36</option>
        <option value="38">38</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
        <option value="42">42</option>
        <option value="44">44</option>
        <option value="46">46</option>
        <option value="48">48</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        
    </select><div class="item1">
<textarea  data-bind="value: textContent" Placeholder="Type text to append"></textarea></div>
<div class="item2">
<textarea data-bind="value: textContent" Placeholder="Type text to append"></textarea></div>
<div class="item3">
<textarea data-bind="value: textContent" Placeholder="Type text to append"></textarea></div>
<button data-bind="click: addNew">Generate New Div</button>

<div class="container">
<div data-bind="foreach:items" class="fix_backround">
    <div href="#" class="item1" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
        <span data-bind="click:$parent.remove">[x]</span><br/><br/>
        <center><span class="text" data-bind="text:$data"></span><input class="edit_text"/></center>
    </div>
    <div href="#" class="item2" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
        <span data-bind="click:$parent.remove">[x]</span><br/><br/>
        <center><span class="text" data-bind="text:$data"></span><input class="edit_text"/></center>
    </div>
    <div href="#" class="item3" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
        <span data-bind="click:$parent.remove">[x]</span><br/><br/>
        <center><span class="text" data-bind="text:$data"></span><input class="edit_text"/></center>
    </div>
</div>
</div><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem is, whenever you type something in 1st Textarea and blur out then 2nd and 3rd text areas are also updated with the same content of 1st.

This is happening because of the data binding which is registered on textarea tag.
 **data-bind="value: textContent"**

Once you remove this attribute from textarea tag then 3 textareas can be edited separately.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: As you haven't specified any default values, it would be empty.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, how about this?

1.

```
<div class="container">
  <div data-bind="foreach:items" class="fix_backround">
    <div href="#" class="item1" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
      <span data-bind="click:$parent.remove">[x]</span>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <center>
        <span class="text" data-bind="text:$data"></span><input class="edit_text"/>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your knockout HTML is creating three divs per item in the `items` array. I don't think this is what you want. The code above creates just one div per item in the `items` array. The more items you add, the more divs you will get.

2.

JS:

```
var vm=function(){
  var self=this;
  self.items=ko.observableArray();
  self.textContent1 = ko.observable('');
  self.textContent2 = ko.observable('');
  self.textContent3 = ko.observable('');
  self.init=function(){
    self.items([]);
  }
// ...
```

HTML:

```
<div class="item1">
  <textarea  data-bind="value: textContent1" Placeholder="Type text to append"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="item2">
  <textarea data-bind="value: textContent2" Placeholder="Type text to append"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="item3">
  <textarea data-bind="value: textContent3" Placeholder="Type text to append"></textarea>
</div>
```

You need three seperate data bindings for your text input boxes if you want them to act independently.

3.

```
self.addNew = function() {
  var content = [ 
    self.textContent1(), 
    self.textContent2(), 
    self.textContent3()
  ].filter(function(item) {
    return item !== ''
  });

  content.forEach(function(item) { self.items.push(item); })
  self.textContent1('');
  self.textContent2('');
  self.textContent3('');
}
```

Modify your `addNew` function to get data from all the text boxes, filter out those with no content, and append those with content to the `items` array.

Comment: i do not know what im doing wrong but it is not working

Comment: i do not know what im doing wrong but it is not working here is all my code please help https://jsfiddle.net/barronfidel7/3m99qq6j/2/

Comment: working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n8wpo1zg/

you were missing whole chunks of your existing code - so i added them back in, there were also some external resources like Knockout.js and jQuery missing, so I added them. Finally a few syntax errors like missing `}`'s and `)`'s. Hope that helps!